# How does RDFa Lite with Schema.org for Books

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool, rdfa

sorry for my English...

I build my **RDFa Lit** with **Schema.org** for my Article, it to show,

```
<main vocab="http://schema.org"> 
<article  typeof="NewsArticle">

  <h1 property="headline name"></h1>

    <link property="image" href="" />

  <meta property="name" content="" />
  <meta property="mainEntityOfPage" content="" />
  <meta property="datePublished" content="2019-08-07" />

<span property="dateModified" content="2019-10-14">
  <span property="publisher" typeof="Organization">
    <meta property="name" content="" />
     <span property="logo" typeof="ImageObject">
 <link property="contentUrl url" href=""  title=""/>
</span>
</span>
</span>




  <div property="text">  </div>



 <span property="author" typeof="Person" >
  <meta property="name" content="" />
  </span>
```

Now I to want to do similar for Books, I will offer on my website free e-Books, not only but the majority.

Can please someone explain me how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "Now I to want to do similar for Books" but check this out: https://schema.org/Book

You can set micro-formatting for things like `bookFormat`, `isbn`, `numberOfPages`, `author`, `contributor`, `datePublished`, `genre`, `license` and a lot more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with "Now I to want to do similar for Books", I to means that I'll build Page with **RDA Lite** and **Schema.org** for Books...

Comment: Well, I hope that link helps you!

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I think that I should more to research...